# SwiftUI: onDismiss not get called

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, xcode11, swift5

my issue is that `onDismiss` in `.sheet` does not get called if i programmatically dismiss the view. If i normally dismiss the view by swiping it down `onDismiss` get's called normally.

view 1:

```swift
HStack {
    Text("Twittere deine Antwort")
    Spacer()
}
.onTapGesture {
    self.showPostCommentView = true
}
.sheet(isPresented: self.$showPostCommentView, onDismiss: {
    self.optionManager.getTweet() // <--- This does not get called
}) {
    PostTweetView(postCommentTweet: self.optionManager.tweet, postTweetImage: self.image, profileImage: self.imageLoader.image)
}
```

view 2:

```swift
@Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode

Button(action: {
     // some async operations... When finished completion gets called
     self.tweetManager.sendTweet(completion: { self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() })
}) {
    Text("Twittern")
}
```

Comment: This seems like expected behavior? If you dismiss the sheet yourself you don’t need a callback telling you that you dismissed the sheet.

Comment: I want to run code that refreshed the list with new data when i dismiss it programatically. What can I do then?

Comment: Just run the code in your Twittern button. I also think it’s expected behaviour - you might want to do a different thing when you dismiss programmatically (e.g save changes) and when the user dismisses manually (e.g undo)

Comment: @LuLuGaGa the Twittern button is in a seperate view and I the refresh in another view.

Comment: Yes, but you surely refresh on an ObservedObject that drives the data behind both views?

Comment: No only on one view.

Comment: you see the latest code for sheet. https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2019/09/swiftui-actionsheet-example.html

Answer (score 0):

Add an `@escaping` closure to your `PostTweetView` and add your `onDismiss` code to the closure. Make sure your init in `PostTweetView` has all of its local variables assigned as well:

`PostTweetView`:

```swift
@Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
var onDismiss: () -> Void
init(/* All the other local variables in this view */ onDismiss: @escaping () -> Void) {
    // initialize all the other local variables
    self.onDismiss = onDismiss
}

Button(action: {
    // some async operations... When finished completion gets called
    self.tweetManager.sendTweet(completion: { 
        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        self.onDismiss()
    })
}) {
    Text("Twittern")
}
```

`view1` from your original question:

```swift
HStack {
    Text("Twittere deine Antwort")
    Spacer()
}
.onTapGesture {
    self.showPostCommentView = true
}
.sheet(isPresented: self.$showPostCommentView, onDismiss: {
    self.optionManager.getTweet() // <--- This does not get called
}) {
    PostTweetView(postCommentTweet: self.optionManager.tweet, postTweetImage: self.image, profileImage: self.imageLoader.image) {
        self.optionManager.getTweet()
    }
}
```